# possibilites on uploading a file without login in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

In mediawiki, using api i can upload a file. its getting fine . But it will upload only logged in. i need to customize without login anybody can upload a file . I know without login cannot able to access api fuctionalities. Is there any possibilities to do without login ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MediaWiki documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguring_file_uploads):

> By default anonymous uploads are not allowed. You must register and logon before the upload file option appears in the toolbox.

And then from [configuring uploads](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3aConfiguring_file_uploads):

> Is there a way to allow users to upload files without logging in?
>
> That'd be a great help for corporate environments where only a limited number of people can access the wiki (server) anyway...
>
> Edit `SpecialUpload.php` file in the includes folder
>   Comment out the following two lines:

```
 $wgOut->errorPage( 'uploadnologin', 'uploadnologintext' );
 return;
```

> Now users will not have to login to reach the upload form.
>   Simpler method, modify `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgEnableUploads       = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['upload'] = true;
```